# Use directly the dict keys in a Jinja2 template

Tags: python, jinja2

I use some variables in my templates with Jinja2 :

```
# context={USER: "Nico", COUNTRY: "France"}
print template.render(context=context)
```

My templates looks like this :

```
<h1>Hello {{ context.USER }}</h1>
```

What is the solution to use directly the keys of my dict, like this :

```
<h1>Hello {{ USER }}</h1>
```

I have a lot of keys in my dict, so I can't passed them one per one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply your `context` directory with the `**` keyword argument expansion syntax:

```
print template.render(**context)
```

Each key in `context` is then applied as if you passed it in as a separate keyword argument.